# ¿Cómo se puede obtener el error global de una red?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Estoy utilizando la libreria scikit-learn para python, donde entreno una red neuronal, necesito es obtener el error global de la red para tener presente el descenso del gradiente.

```
import pandas as pd  
import sklearn  
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split  
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier  
import matplotlib.pyplot  as plt

#red BackPropagation
data = pd.read_csv('data_set.csv')   
x = data.ix[:,0:30]   
y = data.ix[:,31]  

Xent,Xtest,yent,ytest = train_test_split(x,y)  
red = MLPClassifier( max_iter=10000, hidden_layer_sizes=(15),solver='lbfgs', activation = 'logistic')  
red.fit(Xent,yent)  

print('training: {:.5f}'.format(red.score(Xent,yent)))  
print('Test: {:.5f}'.format(red.score(Xtest,ytest)))
```

Gracias